# React js to refresh page after onClick has been called

Tags: reactjs

I've been following one of the MERN stack tutorials online (making a simple todo app), and decided to go off-script a little bit.  I wanted to add a button to delete a specific item.  The delete function is working fine, however it requires the user to manually refresh the page after they click the delete button in order to see the new list of elements in my database (MongoDB).  I'd like the page to automatically refresh after the click event, however I'm not sure where to start.  Within the react render there is a table, which references a variable to actually assemble the components of the table - this is where the delete button exists.  Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

const Todo = props => (
    <tr>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_title}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_description}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_responsible}</td>
        <td className={props.todo.todo_completed ? 'completed' : ''}>{props.todo.todo_priority}</td>
        <td>
            <Link to={"/edit/"+props.todo._id}>Edit</Link>
        </td>
        <td>
            {/* this is where the delete happens */}
            <button onClick={ () =>
                axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+props.todo._id)
                    .then(console.log("Deleted: " + props.todo._id))                    
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
            >Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
)

export default class TodosList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {todos: []};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ todos: res.data });
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            })
    }

    todoList() {
        return this.state.todos.map(function(currentTodo, i){
            return <Todo todo={currentTodo} key={i} />;
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Todos List</h3>
                <table className="table table-striped" style={{ marginTop: 20 }} >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Responsible</th>
                            <th>Priority</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th>Remove Item</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        { this.todoList() }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone on here can get me pointed in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: Don't delete, just call get api in the callback function of delete call. You could do that by passing get function call as a prop to `Todo` component.

Comment: Your mistake has been to think that items get to remove themselves. They don't: a button should tell the *TodoList* that an item should be removed, since the *TodoList* is the component that knows anything about todo items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the specific item from `TodosList` component state after you have successfully deleted the item from `Todo` component. For that you can

1) add a method in `TodosList` component.

```
deleteItemHandler = (id) => {
 const updatedTodos = this.state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id);
 this.setState({todos: updatedTodos})
}
```

2) pass the method `deleteItemHandler` as props to `Todo` component

```
todoList() {
    return this.state.todos.map((currentTodo, i) => {
       return <Todo todo={currentTodo} deleteItem={this.deleteItemHandler} key={i} />;
   })
}
```

3) use it after item is successfully deleted

```
<td>
   {/* this is where the delete happens */}
   <button onClick={ () =>
       axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+props.todo._id)
          .then(() => props.deleteItem(props.todo._id))                    
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    >Delete</button>
</td>
```

**Another way**

Instead deleting item from `TodosList` component you can also update the state. For that you can

1) add method that updates in `TodosList` component

```
 updateStateHandler = () => { 
     axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/')
        .then(res => {
             this.setState({ todos: res.data });
        })
        .catch(function(err){
            console.log(err);
       })
  }
```

2) pass the method `updateStateHandler` as props to `Todo` component

```
todoList() {
    return this.state.todos.map((currentTodo, i) => {
       return <Todo todo={currentTodo} updateState={this.updateStateHandler} key={i} />;
   })
}
```

3) use it after item is successfully deleted

```
<td>
   {/* this is where the delete happens */}
   <button onClick={ () =>
       axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+props.todo._id)
          .then(() => props.updateState())                    
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    >Delete</button>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks, both changes give me this error _TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateStateHandler' of undefined_

Comment: you need to bind the anonymous function inside `map`. use arrow function

Comment: Thanks for the update.  That eliminates the error, but still doesn't update the page after the delete.

Comment: use `then(() => props.updateState()) ` instead of `then(props.updateState())`

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this

```
export default class TodosList extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {todos: []};
        this.fetchTodos = this.fetchTodos.bind(this);
    }

    fetchTodos() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/todos/')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({ todos: res.data });
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.fetchTodos();
    }

    todoList() {
        return this.state.todos.map((currentTodo, i) => {
            return <Todo todo={currentTodo} fetchTodos={this.fetchTodos}  key={i} />;
        })
    }
   ...
```

Todo:

```
        <td>
            {/* this is where the delete happens */}
            <button onClick={ () =>
                axios.delete('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+props.todo._id)
                    .then(() => {
                         console.log("Deleted: " + props.todo._id);
                         props.fetchTodos();
                     })                    
                    .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
            >Delete</button>
        </td>
```

Comment: I'm getting a failed to compile error on `componentDidMount() { fetchTodos();}`  the error saying that _'fetchTodos' is not defined  no-undef_

Comment: edit the answer, try now i missed `this` in  `this.fetchTodos`

Comment: Thank you sir.  Resolved that error, but now there's an error on this line: `return <Todo todo={currentTodo} fetchTodos={this.fetchTodos}  key={i} />;` saying _TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchTodos' of undefined_

Comment: Hi, what does "this.fetchTodos = this.fetchTodos.bind(this);" mean? what is the function of that?

Comment: its how we assing the function to class scope.. using `bind`, however we dont need this now by using arrow function which takes the scope of parent implicity.

Answer (score 0):

The authority that renders the table is your `TodosList` class, so *it* needs to be told to do the deleting:

```
class TodosList extends ... {
  ...
  todoList() {
    return this.state.todos.map((currentTodo, i) => {
      let onDelete = () => {
        this.removeItem(i);
      };
      // NEVER use an array position as key. The key is meant to uniquely
      // identify the _item itself_ and is used in DOM diffing. Moving elements
      // inside an array does not change those elements in the slightest and only
      // requires moving DOM nodes around, but if you use array position as key,
      // what you've now done is said that _everything in the DOM node has changed_
      // So: don't do that. Use a real, item based, value.
      return <Todo todo={currentTodo} key={currentTodo.id} onDelete={onDelete}/>;

      // Of course this assumes todo items have an `id` property.
      // If they don't, pick another property _on the todo item_ that
      // uniquely identifies it.
    });
  }

  removeItem(i) {
    let todos = this.state.todos;
    todos.splice(i,1);
    // This single call now results in all the UI updates that you
    // need to have happen: the todo item is no longer in the state,
    // and so its DOM node will be removed from the page. And because
    // we're now using real keys, React will not touch any of the other
    // DOM nodes. The UI update is near-instant.
    this.setState({ todos });
  }
  ...
}
```

Then the individual buttons can call their own onDelete once deleting has happened:

```
const deleteThisItem = () => {
  axios
  .delete('http://localhost:4000/todos/'+props.todo._id)
  .then(this.props.onDelete())                    
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
};

<button onClick={deleteThisItem}>delete</button>
```

So the flow is:

- TodoList knows all the todo items,
- TodoList generates UI for each todo item,
- item UI includes a button that will call **TodoList**'s item deletion function, which will update the **TodoList** state
- simply by virtue of removing an item from that state and calling `setState` with that change, React will render what needs to be rendered.